# Disconnect mapped drive with "Reconnect at logon" setting on Vista

Tags: windows, networking, windows-vista, mappeddrive, login

How to disable the *Reconnect at logon* setting for a mapped network drive on Vista? How to disconnect already mapped drives?

Comment: Are you wanting to do this as a once off, or as a task via SMS or something on your network for all users?

Comment: I want just to turn it off for a specific mapping.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

to disconnect, use:

```
net use Z: /d
```

Windows will not try to re-connect the drive when logging on again (unless the drive is actually being connected in a logon script or similar, of course).

Answer (score 2):

NET USE /PERSISTENT:NO will turn off persistence for future network mappings. If you already have the mapping, you need to delete it and recreate it after to change the setting.

Comment: Works patially: persistence is OFF for future mappings, but I'm not able to kill my existing mapping...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to first disconnect from the server, then map it again to change it.

Comment: It doesn't work, when I log off and log on again I still have a mapped drive,

Comment: my experience so far is also that this procedure is not sufficient; i end up with the drive still mapping automatically.